# How can I find the resultant of these coplanar forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors

[image]

I don't have the angles and I believe I cannot find them using the distances given as they are not the same quantity as the forces. How can I find the resultant, what am I meant to do

Comment: Use trigonometry!

Comment: Hi Eugene, you can actually find the angles by the distances given to you. If this doesn't seem right to you, as you said in your post then I recommend you revise vector decomposition. As a hint, maths or the coordinates you are using don't differentiate between what is distance and what is a vector. For them, both of these are just lines.

Comment: @Farcher but if I use trig, then line OX would be 800, which cannot be since OF1 is 800N( hypotenus can't be equal to any other side). Also the tan and sin won't correspond

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist , would that mean the horizontal component of the first force of 800N will also be 800N?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing lengths and the magnitude of forces - they are not the same !

For example, the upper right rectangle has side lengths $800$ and $600$ so it is clearly made up of two $3:4:5$ triangles, and its diagonal has length $1000$. The cosines of the angles between this diagonal and the sides are $0.8$ for the longer side and $0.6$ for the shorter side. So the components of a force with magnitude $F$ along the diagonal will be $0.8F$ along the longer side and $0.6F$ along the shorter side. $F$ can take any value - in this case it is $800$ N.

Comment: Oh I understand now. The force of 800N is not equal to the length of the right angle triangle . Thanks alot